# Pointer in a function "expected expression before = token"

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor

I try to learn using pointers in functions by "simply" counting a circle. i get the error `expected expression before '=' token` but cant understand why. saying expected expression before.. is unclear to me, what kind of?

```
#define PI = 3.1415f

void circle(float *wert) {

    *wert = ( (*wert) * (*wert) * PI );

}

int main(void) {

    float radius;

    printf("radius input: ");
    scanf("%f", &radius);    
    circle(&radius);
    printf("the circle size will be: %f", &radius);

}
```

Comment: `&radius` in `printf` should be `radius`.

Comment: thank you, also #define PI = 3.1415f should be #define PI 3.1415f without =

Comment: If you'd included `math.h` you'd have found that `PI` is already pre`#define`d.

Comment: but i cant even understand the error output the error was at line 12 where i use the math but pi is defined earlier and in line 12 PI is not before the = sign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define PI = 3.1415f
```

should be

```
#define PI 3.1415f
```

The macro PI is replaced when used in the code by 3.1415

Comment: it compiles with no errors but the circle of radius 5 is not 0.0000. but thats the output. do you know why?

Comment: @muni, change `&radius` to `radius` in the `printf`.

Comment: @muni &var gives the address of the varaible if you want the value just use the variable name

Comment: oh my god i'm that dumb xD you explained me that about half an hour ago!! i thougt thats just the case when i explicit handle addresses.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define PI = 3.1415f
```

There should be no `=` here. Change into

```
#define PI (3.1415f)
```

Comment: it compiles with no errors but the circle of radius 5 is not 0.0000. but thats the output. do you know why?

Comment: While using parenthesis to protect macros can't hurt, I can't see what lexical ambiguities can be solved in the case of a simple float litteral. I'd be interested if you can provide an example where omitting them causes problems, because I have personnally never used parenthesis with such constants.

Comment: @SirDarius No, I don't have such an example. It's just a matter of habit.